# Low/muffled voices in Ground Zeroes?

Tags: ps4, metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I just bought a PS4 and started playing Ground Zeroes on it. All voices sound like they are in the background, or feel muffled. I can barely hear them.

How can I fix this? I did not have this issue with any PS3 games on a PS3. There appears to be no sound settings in GZ.

I have no other PS4 games to test this with. The PS4 menu sounds are okay.

I do have a receiver, but it's set to stereo. My TV is muted. The audio connector is optical.

Comment: I don't have that issue, and I'm playing Ground Zeroes on a PS4 too.

Comment: Check your settings for the sound on the PS4 itself, there could be a setting gone wrong in there. Or it could be playing sound to the wrong location making it sound muffled. Try a different game or app to see if the sound problem stays

Comment: @Dupree3 Hmm there are really not many output sound settings on the PS4.

Comment: Don't suppose you're on a 5.1 audio system? I dont' have one to test, but some people have reported issues with the PS4 basically outputting 7.1 to 5.1 sound systems and thus missing 2 channels. More details: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=789584

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka My receiver is set to stereo, nothing more.

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka I'm using 5.1 and I don't have this issue at all

Comment: One idea. If you're running stereo/component style connections, make sure your PS4 is configured for Stereo. I had this problem with Resident Evil on the Wii U as well. If I set the game system for Stereo instead of Surround, the game output the sound correctly. The problem was the Dolby encoding was broken and dropping the center channel. http://www.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/PS4_Audio_Problems

Comment: @BryanC. I'm using optical. Center channel sounds like the right direction though.

Comment: I'd still try changing the PS4 to stereo to troubleshoot. I'm doing some reading now that indicates there are lots of complaints about the DTS compatibility on this game on both PS4 and Xbox One. Also, try setting "Linear PCM" if you have it set for bitstream.

Comment: @BryanC. That's where I get confused. I see no stereo option etc on the PS4 menus.

Comment: Sorry, just try setting the sound to Linear PCM.